# Dynamodb batch put if item does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDB does not support batch update, it supports batch put only.

But is it possible to batchPut only of item with key does not exist?

Answer (score 3):

In the [`batchWriteItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#batchWriteItem-property), there is the following note:

> For example, you cannot specify conditions on individual put and delete requests, and BatchWriteItem does not return deleted items in the response.

Instead, I would recommend using `putItem` with a conditional expression. Towards the bottom of the [`putItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property) documentation there is the following note:

> [...] To prevent a new item from replacing an existing item, use a
>   conditional expression that contains the `attribute_not_exists` function
>   with the name of the attribute being used as the partition key for the
>   table [...]

So make sure to add the following to `ConditionExpression` (using NodeJS syntax here)

```
const params = {
    Item: {
        userId: {
            S: "Beyonce",
        }
    },
    ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(userId)"
};
```

Comment: put item is for individual item , that will make the write slow , if batch write would have supported item exist check it would have been single network call for multiple writes and faster in performance.

Comment: @ShushantArora - Instead you could `batchGetItem` and check which ones are *not* returned and store this as `doesNotExist`. Then use the `doesNotExist` list to create your `batchWriteItem` request. Would you need an example of this approach?

Comment: Yea why do so complicate when Amazon could have added the condition expression in the batch write eh?